# Moving files to folders based on Name and Course Code with Batch File

Tags: file, batch-file, directory

I've been searching for a solution and have found *similar* solutions but they have either been with fixed length file names, or been used to sort files within a folder, rather than moving them.

What I'm attempting to do is when a staff member places, for example, a file in **S drive** named:

```
Bloggs Joe AHC20410 Student Forms.pdf
```

The batch file (run at certain times of the day) will move the files to the **H drive**, into the folder:

```
H:\Student Records Current\Bloggs Joe AHC20410
```

So, just for example **S Drive** could look like this when the batch file is run:

```
Bloggs Joe AHC20410 Student Forms.pdf
Bloggs Joe AHC20410 Evidence.jpg
Doe Jane AHC31010 Workbook.doc
Doe Joe AHC20410 Images.png
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See `move /?`. Enclose paths with spaces in quotes. Type `help` for a list of commands. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820569/trouble-with-renaming-folders-and-sub-folders-using-batch for some conventions at command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%d IN (
  'dir /b /ad "%destdir%\*ahc*" 2^>nul ^|findstr /i /r /c:"AHC[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"'
  ) DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\%%d*"  2^>nul ^|findstr /i /r /c:" AHC[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] "'
 ) DO (
  ECHO(MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\%%d\"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

assumed that the destination directories already exist.

Essentially, find all of the directorynames containing `ahc`, and filter for `ahc followed by 5 numerics` for good measure. Assign these strings to `%%d`.

Then for each `%%d` found, look for source files that start `%%d` and contain the string `ahc followed by 5 numerics` and both preceded and succeeded by a space.

Bang the names together and show the result...

Comment: Thank you very much @Magoo for taking the time to write the code, my batch file skills are pretty rusty.

I was confused for a bit when the code found the source and destination, but didn't copy... But eventually noticed a missing ')'. Works perfectly!