# Can I Use the Set Command Twice With the Same Variable Name?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Example code:

```
    @echo off
    set money=0
    echo How Much Do You Want To Deposit?
    set /p "moneyPut=>"
    set /a money=%money% + %moneyPut%
```

Can this work?

Comment: Why didn't you just try it?

Comment: I did, it didn't function correctly.

Comment: That's probably because of `>`. `<`, `>`, and `|` have special meaning and are the first thing parsed on a command line. If you want a prompt character see `choice /?` and `prompt /?`.

Comment: See here for a list of punctuation - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820569/trouble-with-renaming-folders-and-sub-folders-using-batch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that will work. The assignment of money= is the last thing that occurs. The current value of %money% is evaluated first, like most (all?) other programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question; yes, you can. The old value is simply overwritten with a new value. You can use the old value to define the new value though, just like you use the old value of `money` together with the value of `moneyput`, to define the new value of `money`, in your example code.
I tested your example code, and found it to be working fine, so more information on how exactly you find it isn't working would be useful.