# What is the meaning of batch 'switches'

Tags: batch-file

I have heard about all sorts of different batch commands like echo. but then there's different switches like /p or /I ect. what on the planet, is their difference?
and what is the difference between
!variable! and %variable%??? and %%i
please tell me, who knows what advantages there could be.
thanks

Comment: This may be the first question I've ever seen on StackOverflow where I could honestly say that the answer to this question legitimately will be too long to post.

Comment: Have you ever thought of reading the documentation??

Comment: Yeah, course! i dont get it

Comment: Just one more thing, how do I clear the content marketing f a .txt file using batch?

Answer (score 1):

There are commands like `echo` and `dir` and `findstr`.

For some commands, there are `switches` that modify how the command runs.

```
dir
```

will generate a directory-list

```
dir /od
```

will generate a directory-list in order of the dates that the files/directories were last modified.

A well-behaved command is self-documenting; that is

```
commandname /?
```

will show documentation.

This pribciple is largely supported by the built-in commands supplied as part of the OS and console-oriented commands provided by third parties.

BUT

Other operating systems use `-` or `--` instead of `/` and when these commands are "ported" from those operating systems to Windows, they still require the alternative switch-indicators. It's a matter of knowing on a case-by-case basis.

The values of variables within a batch file are fundamentally retrieved using `%var%`. There are two exceptions - the value of a parameter supplied to the batch or subroutine is accessed by `%n` (where n=1-9) and `%%x` where `x` is the `metavariable` in a `for` loop (ie. the loop-control variable.) Bizarrely, `%%x` here is one of the few cases where batch is case-sensitive.

When batch executes a routine, it first `parses` the line (checks it for validity) and then `executes` it. A logical line may be many physical lines long. As part of the *parsing* process, any `%var%` is replaced by the value of that variable **at the time the line is parsed**.

Consequently, in a `for` loop, `%var%` is replaced by its value at `parse-time` so if it is changed by the loop, `%var%` will appear to have a constant value. To access the **current** value of `var` in the loop as it is changed, use `!var!` **BUT** in order to use the `!var!` syntax, you need to have previously executed `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`.

Answer (score 0):

Type `Help` in a command prompt.

For each command type either `help command` (eg `help dir`) or `command /?` (eg `dir /?`)

For commands with sub modes like `reg` command type `reg /?` then `reg query /?`.

See [Trouble with renaming folders and sub folders using Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820569/trouble-with-renaming-folders-and-sub-folders-using-batch) for !var!

> %variablename% a inbuilt or user set environmental variable
>
> !variablename! a user set environmental variable expanded at execution time, turned with SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion command

See `setlocal /?` and also `for /?`for an explanation on when and why to do it.