# What does a pair of commas mean when used as a destination for cmd copy

Tags: syntax, cmd, copy

I recently saw a cpoy command in a batch script that looked like this:

```
copy <file> /B+ ,,/Y
```

I know the /B means to do a binary copy. I believe the + is just affirming the /B command, but am not sure.  I know the /Y means yes to all and accepts all prompts for confirmation.  I haven't been able to find anything about what the ,, is doing.  I've run the command on a dummy file  to see if anything changed, but I could not find a copied file anywhere.

**What does** `copy <file> /B+ ,,/Y` **do?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It updates the file time.

```
, used with copy to indicate missing parameters. This updates the files 
modified date. E.G. copy /b file1,,
```

See my list here [Trouble with renaming folders and sub folders using Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820569/trouble-with-renaming-folders-and-sub-folders-using-batch)

So it is concatenating 1 file. That updates last modified.

Source is MSDos 6.22 Help file that can't be opened in 64 bit windows. Dos help files are compressed so can't be read by notepad.

Comment: Thanks!  I haven't been able to find that information anywhere, and it's not in `copy /?`  Do you remember where you came across it originally?  Are you aware of some sort of more complete official documentation stowed in some corner of microsofts servers somewhere?

Comment: Comes from MSDos 6.22 Help file that can't be used in 64 bit windows.

Comment: _can't be used in 64 bit windows._  ... That's mildly annoying.

Comment: The Dos help files are compressed so notepad can't help. Dos help files are displayed by QBasic program. If you have a virtual machine I can give you the files I just uploaded to skydrive the files in Dos622help.zip. https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E2F0CE17A268A4FA!121&authkey=!AAFg7j814-lJtmI&ithint=folder%2cres