# File input from terminal C program

Tags: c, bash, cmd

I am beginning a C project, and my professor expects us to use the following format to run our program:

```
./prog stop_words_dir < chapter.txt
```

It is my understanding that this means I am executing a program named `prog` that takes a directory as its parameter (in this case `stop_words_dir`) and uses a specific file from that directory named `chapter.txt`.

1. Am I correct?
2. If so, is this format Unix (more specifically bash) specific?
3. What does the equivalent command in Windows look like?
4. What is the benefit to using the `<` as opposed to a second parameter
5. How would I access `chapter.txt` in a C program with the given format? (I am aware of how to do this with two parameters)

Comment: It appears unix, windows has backslashes rather than forward slashes - but windows accepts either so it will work on windows. Start a program named `prog` in the current directory (`.`), load a file, folder, or whatever it is of words with parameter 1 (the only parameter), then check standard input which has a file directed into it. See here for my list of punctuation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820569/trouble-with-renaming-folders-and-sub-folders-using-batch

Comment: If you are designing the program then there is not much advantage to piping, as in using "<" in "< chapter.txt". The "<" is designed for use with programs that someone else wrote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. Am I correct?

Not entirely.  The shell (any Unix-like shell — Bash certainly, but also Bourne, Korn and other shells, including even the C shell family) runs the program named `prog` from the current directory, with the string `stop_words_dir` as an argument, and with its standard input reading from the file in the current directory called `chapter.txt`.

> 2. If so, is this format Unix (more specifically Bash) specific?

The only thing that makes this Unix-specific is the use of `/`.  On Windows, with the native shells, the `/` would lead to confusion (certainly for the `cmd.exe` 'shell').

> 3. What does the equivalent command in Windows look like?

```
    prog stop_words_dir < chapter.txt
```

> 4. What is the benefit to using the '<' as opposed to a second parameter.

Primarily, the shell opens the file and deals with the error if it does not exist.  If the `<` were not used, your program would have to do the opening, and handle the errors.  Secondarily, you can use just `scanf()` and `getchar()` to read from standard input, rather than needing to use `fscanf()` or `getc()` (or relatives) to read the data.  It is only a minor benefit.  Typically, you write your program so that it processes any given file stream, and simply pass `stdin` when the program needs to read from standard input.  The function is then more general — and reusable.

> 5. How would I access `chapter.txt` in a C program (with the given format. I am aware of how to do this with two parameters)?

With standard I/O functions that read from standard input, such as `scanf()` or `getchar()`, or with the general I/O functions but specifying `stdin` as the file stream (such as `fgets()` or `fread()` — or `fscanf()` or `getc()`, or …).

Comment: Upticked. the description of the IO redirection and its program-reuse value is spot-on (not surprisingly). And the distinction of OS vs. shell equally informative. Ok then, I'm off to delete the answer I was crafting =P

Comment: I've instead given you the most helpful answer, as you answered each of my questions fully, although I do still appreciate Jonny Henly's answer.

Comment: I assume that the only reason why "./prog" is used is to force execution of the program from **only** the current directory. In Windows using just "prog" would tell Windows to search for "prog" in other specified locations. If I am correct about Unix/Linux then just using "prog" is **not** the equivalent in Windows.

Comment: @user34660: I am not sure whether the `cmd.exe` always looks in the current directory when you type a simple command name. I think it does, but I am far from certain. If it does not, then the `./prog` on Unix becomes `.\prog` on Windows.

Comment: Instead of saying "command name", in this context I would say "console program", but that is strictly a difference in terminology and not important. What is important is that yes, Windows will definitely look in the current directory first.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I correct?

No, but you are close.

> It is my understanding that this means I am executing a program named `prog` that takes a directory as it's parameter (in this case `stop_words_dir`) and uses a specific file from that directory named `chapter.txt`

You're executing a program named `prog` that takes any number of passed in arguments, in this case 1 (`stop_words_dir`), and you're redirecting standard input to the contents of `chapter.txt`, which is in the current directory (`./`) it may or may not be in the `stop_words_dir` directory.

Note that the argument `stop_words_dir` has to be handled in the program by using the second index of `argv`, which is `argv[1]`.

> If so, is this format Unix (more specifically bash) specific?

I'm fairly certain that this is Unix specific, but I'm not positive.

> What does the equivalent command in Windows look like?

A Google search should provide you with the basic Windows `cmd` command to execute a program with one argument and redirected standard input.

> What is the benefit to using the '<' as opposed to a second parameter

`<` basically means switch keyboard input with the content of the input stream given, or redirect standard input. A second command argument would have to be dealt with differently, for example opening and reading from a file.

> How would I access chapter.txt in a C program (with the given format. I am aware of how to do this with two parameters)?

The contents of `chapter.txt` are read using methods in `C` to retrieve keyboard input from a user, like `scanf`.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. This answered most of my questions, everything else I need to know I will be able to find out now. Unfortunately trying to google "use of < in terminal" is not very helpful. Answers will be much easier to find now that I know that it is called the redirection of standard input.

Comment: @Lance_P no probelm at all, let me know if you need any more help. You're right that trying to google the meaning of non word operations like `<` doesn't always yield helpful results.

Comment: It might help to explain how it can be determined that prog "takes any number of passed in arguments". We know it takes one but how do we know it can take more?