# Create file with name of variable the write content of another file - first line

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to make a file and name it `%file_name%`+.txt
basically i want to create a file and name it the content of a variable + "_temp.txt" and in the same directory.
then write to it the content of of another file without the first line. read that line
and write the content of the new file to the old one and continue that until no more lines are left and delete the new file.

does that make any sense?

Comment: It is unclear question ?? please edit and explain more your request and post some code that you have tried until now !

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %A in (c:\windows\win.ini) do echo %A >> Newfile.txt
```

See `help`, `for /?`, `echo /?`, and a list of punctuation at [Trouble with renaming folders and sub folders using Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820569/trouble-with-renaming-folders-and-sub-folders-using-batch).

In a batch file, as `for /?` explains, use `%%A` rather than `%A` when typing.