# Batch script vs command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ogr2ogr

When I run following command in cmd prompt it works:

```
for /R %f in (*.shp) do ogr2ogr -nln merge -update -append merge.shp %f
```

but when I run it from .bat file it does not work. Saying -nln was unexpected.

Is there anyway I could run this from .bat file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%` character has a special meaning for command line parameters and `FOR` parameters.

To treat a percent as a regular character, double it: `%%`

When you execute it from a batch file, you should write it like this :

```
@echo on
for /R %%f in (*.shp) do ogr2ogr -nln merge -update -append merge.shp %%f 
pause
```

See this for more info : http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

Comment: is there any guide I can follow for batch scripting?

Comment: @kinkajou i edit my answer, so, take a look at the link above ;)

Comment: Type `Help` in a command prompt. Then either `command /?` or `help command`. The thing causing you grief is in `for /?`. Here's a cheat guide to punctuation in the command prompt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820569/trouble-with-renaming-folders-and-sub-folders-using-batch.

Comment: Doubling the `%` signs for batch files one of the first things mentioned when typing `for /?` in command prompt...