# Run an exe file on multiple clients from local server

Tags: batch-file

Noob here. I have a local fileserver set up. I want to write a batch script that runs a certain name.exe on every client that is active on the server. So basically, when I run the batch file, name.exe runs on every connected, active client. Not sure how to go about this.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here! Your question is way too broad for this site!

Answer (score 0):

To generate a list of computers that are turned on, (in a batch file use `%%A` rather than `%A` when typing interactively)

```
for /f "skip=3 delims=\" %A in ('net view ^| findstr /v /C:"The command completed successfully"') do Echo %A >> "%userprofile%\desktop\computername.txt"
```

To run a program use (**NB:** remote programs are invisible on the remote computer because you can't interfere with a user). Note the use of double backslashes for the command line.

```
wmic /node:@"%userprofile%\desktop\computername.txt" /failfast:on process call create "c:\\windows\\notepad.exe"
```

See `wmic /?`, `wmic process /?`, `wmic process get /?`, `wmic process set /?`, `wmic process call /?`, `wmic /format /?`, `wmic /node /?`, and `wmic /failfast /?`. Also `for /?`, `net help view` (`net view /?` is short help) and `findstr /?`.

To see what punctuation means see [Trouble with renaming folders and sub folders using Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820569/trouble-with-renaming-folders-and-sub-folders-using-batch)