# How to type response to raw input on terminal via batch file?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file that will automatically run a python script. After `python main.py` is executed, the script asks for what serial port the user is using (using the raw input function in python).

I want to automatize the process by trying all the different COM ports until we find the correct port so users do not have to enter the COM port.

Basically I am just wondering what batch command is used to write to the terminal? I'm new to batch and I couldn't find any information about my specific question...

I have tried this so far:

```
    main.py
    echo COM3
    pause
```

But the "COM3" does not get entered in to the terminal. Would really appreciate any help thanks so much!

Comment: `echo hi > COM3`. See a list of punctuation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820569/trouble-with-renaming-folders-and-sub-folders-using-batch

Comment: That really threw ME for a loop.  I thought he was talking about RAW (non-canonized) input on a UNIX tty!

Answer (score 0):

Try a pipe, which directs the output of one command to the input of another:

```
echo COM3 | main.py
```

Ideally, however, your `main.py` would be written to take the port on the command line, instead of prompting for it (or only prompting if it's not found on the command line). Like this:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    port = raw_input("Enter port number: ")
else:
    port = sys.argv[1]
```

Then you can simply do `main.py COM3`.