# How can I get cmd to filter out all the unnecessary stuff?

Tags: windows, cmd

I'm running a script and it's currently cluttering the CMD prompt. The important parts are only every few lines, they're in a very distinct green as to help. But now that the script has been running for a while there is more clutter.

My question is, can I filter out words? So that I can see only the important stuff on my CMD prompt?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: I hope screenshots will suffice. Whoops. I hit enter, didn't realize that would post the comment. Give me a sec to edit in the screenshot.

So the stuff in light green is all I want to see. The stuff in the red box.

http://i.imgur.com/lNCvF3n.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Somecommand | Findstr /c:"<PKMN>"
```

Filters output through `Findstr`. See `Findstr /?`. See [Trouble with renaming folders and sub folders using Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820569/trouble-with-renaming-folders-and-sub-folders-using-batch) for punctuation meaning.