# "set /p var=" command with batch file AND opening batch with batch on a different window

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a game with a level selection. If you can't find a solution, can you just make me a new level selection? Anyways, my problem is, I am making the player choose between levels by typing either level 0, "tutorial" level 1, level 2 and level 3. Every time I try to think of a solution I hurt my head. I'm only 11 so that's not a surprise. Here is the code that I need help with:

```
echo what level do you want?
echo (must have unlocked previous level to play the next)
echo.
echo.
echo tutorial ( lvl0 )
echo lvl1
echo lvl2
echo lvl3
set /p level=enter lvl here:
if level=lvl0 goto let
if level not =lvl1 goto le1
if level not =lvl2 goto le2
if level not =lvl3 goto le3
```

I also want to make sure that they can't go in level 1 until the tutorial is complete, can't enter level 2 until level 1 is complete and so on. How I am going to get out of this? If you need to ask questions to answer this one, ask it in the comments and I will reply. Anyways, I have another question and don't want to wait 90 minutes to post it.

Is there a way of opening a batch file IN a batch file?

I know, it's simple. But can you open it inside of a second window?

This is for the game I mentioned earlier. If I can't, it will ruin a game-play mechanic I wanted to put in the game. Here is how I opened up in the SAME window.

```
echo calling hack services...
call C:\Users\%username%\searches\matrix.bat
```

Comment: yes.... i TOTTALY know what half of that means! especially because i'm 11!

Comment: ok i will do the help thing

Comment: also. by a level system, i mean like mario levels. not level up! rpg levels

Comment: i'm sorry, I've tried using the "help set" system. but i can not understand what half of it means. if you could find a easier to understand solution that would be awesome. thanks Mofi!

Comment: Type `if /?` into a command prompt window, read the help for that command and compare your code with the syntax examples mentioned there...

Comment: @Imprixie "Subscriber certifies to Stack Exchange that Subscriber is an individual (i.e., not a corporate entity) at least 13 years of age." from https://stackexchange.com/legal.

Comment: @user6718734 Read the answer on [How to call a batch file, that is two levels up from the current directory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24725044/3074564) describing the 4 methods to call or start another batch file from within a batch file in same or another process (= console window).

Answer (score 1):

This is what the beginning of help says:

```
C:\Windows\system32>if /?
Performs conditional processing in b

IF [NOT] ERRORLEVEL number command
IF [NOT] string1==string2 command
IF [NOT] EXIST filename command
```

So spaces are important. It is `==` not `=`. And `Not` goes after `if`. Variables need to be in `%` signs.

```
if not %level%==lvl1 goto le1
```

But this makes no sense, got to level 1 if they don't choose it, then the others don't get checked anyway. So there is no need for `not` at all.

In Help `[NOT]` the square brackets means `not` is optional. `Not` reverses the test to not equals rather than equals if `not` is omitted.

```
if %level%==lvl1 goto le1
```

The `choice` command is a better command. See `choice /?`.

Very basic example - note tests need to be in decending order.

```
choice /c 12 
If errorlevel 2 goto Level2
If errorlevel 1 goto Level1
```

You may find an answer at this link useful [Trouble with renaming folders and sub folders using Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820569/trouble-with-renaming-folders-and-sub-folders-using-batch).

Comment: there is one problem tho. how do i make it so you can only enter level 2 if level 1 is completed?

Answer (score 1):

```
**echo what level do you want?
echo (must have unlocked previous level to play the next)
echo.
echo.
echo tutorial ( lvl0 )
echo lvl1
echo lvl2
echo lvl3
:qprompt
set /p level=enter lvl here:
if %level%==lv10 goto let
if %level%==lv11 goto let
if %level%==lv12 goto let
if %level%==lv13 goto let
echo The Answer Is Not One of The Choices! Please Try Again
goto qprompt**
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.