# BATCH> run .exe files which paths are contained in a text file

Tags: batch-file

I'm working on a start script, and I have a text file `output.txt`, containing paths to programs, like:

> ```
> C:/program1.exe
> C:/abab/program2.exe
> ```

How do I now run the programs contained in the text file via a batch script?

Comment: Rename the file to batch and run it. Open in notepad and search for `/` and replace with ` \ ` as that is the windows standard.

Comment: Thanks, this did actually work, the only problem is, that these programs are console-applications, therefore only 1 is ran because it takes the bat window

Comment: Does output.txt really contain a single line containing paths separated by <space><comma><space>?

Comment: No it doesn't its just a list of the paths. I can't get it into stackoverflow: http://hastebin.com/heqiwemuci.tex

Comment: …and what does your start script look like, _(you must have one because you've just reported it working only for one file)_.

Comment: C:\MusicBots\Bot2\sinusbot.exe [NEW LINE]
C:\MusicBots\Bot3\sinusbot.exe [NEW LINE]
C:\MusicBots\TESTBOT_KRXTZ\sinusbot.exe

Comment: I thought that was your output.txt, I'm lookng for your batch script content

Comment: Noodles sugested to just rename my output.txt to output.bat , changing the / to \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %A in ("C:\output.txt") Do Start "" "%A"
```

`Start` starts programs without waiting for them to exit (so new window) and first set of quotes is the window title. `UseBackq` is needed to use quotes around output.txt. See `For /?` and my answer here for how to start programs [Trouble with renaming folders and sub folders using Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820569/trouble-with-renaming-folders-and-sub-folders-using-batch). In a batch use `%%A` and `%A` when typing interactively (I don't use batch files, I keep stuff in one text file and paste parts into a command prompt window,which is interactive).

If they were to be run sequentially then

> Rename the file to batch and run it. Open in notepad and search for / and replace with `\` as that is the windows standard (although autocorrect will fix it without telling you but can sometimes cause problems).

Comment: I had to add another % to the %A variable, now it's working perfectly! Thank you very much! :)