# Issue running Net cmd but with no error (BAT file)

Tags: batch-file, command-line, scripting

I am trying to create a bat file that will run cmd as administrator, then execute net command as shown below:

`runas /user:administrator cmd "net localgroup administrators mjordan /add"`

**The goal is to add whoever the current user is as a local administrator.**

So the first part works like a charm, and asks for the admin password. Upon entering the admin PW however, I do not see said test user under the local admin group. My best guess is I made a syntax error. But oddly enough no errors show up and command-line exits as if it executed.

Also, how would I make this execute and add the current user to the local admin group (thinking in a %username% way)? Not sure I am using the proper terminology, but say the user logged on running this command is `JSmith`. How could I make it add without using his name so it works on any account rather than just `JSmith`

Do you guys notice any errors? ...I am fairly new to creating bat files, and am learning as much as I can, so i know i must have messed up somewhere. Also, any references or study help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I would try: `runas /user:administrator cmd /C "net localgroup administrators mjordan /add"`

Comment: Quotes are in the wrong place as well. `runas /user:administrator "cmd /c net localgroup administrators %username% /add"` will get the current user as that is who is running the command.

Comment: For help see this link for help on symbols http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820569/trouble-with-renaming-folders-and-sub-folders-using-batch. Type `help` then `command /?`. For the `net` command brief help `net /?` and `net localgroup /?` - full help is `net help localgroup`. So type `runas /?` and `cmd /?`. CMD is not needed in your command. So `runas /user:administrator "net localgroup administrators %username% /add"`.

Comment: @Noodles was spot on. That worked like a charm. And thank you for the help and advice. Greatly appreciated.