# Difference between calling "start myapp" and "myapp"

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, command

In a Windows batch file, or in the Command Prompt, what's the difference between calling `start mspaint`, for example, and `mspaint`? They appear to do exactly the same thing.

Another example, where all 4 cases appear to do the same thing. Can you please help me understand what are the subtle differences, if any?

1. `taskmgr`
2. `C:\Windows\System32\Taskmgr.exe`
3. `start taskmgr`
4. `start C:\Windows\System32\Taskmgr.exe`

Follow-up: it looks like `start` opens a separate background command prompt to run the program you write after it (source: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297(v=ws.11).aspx). Is this the same as Linux's `myApp &` format--where you have the `&` suffix?

Comment: To `&` yes it is. In Windows `&` separates multiple lines on one line. `dir c:\ & dir d:\ `. See my summary of characters here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820569/trouble-with-renaming-folders-and-sub-folders-using-batch

Answer (score 2):

---

### Starting a Program

See start /? and call /? for help on all three ways.

### Specify a program name

```
c:\windows\notepad.exe
```

In a batch file the batch will wait for the program to exit. When
typed the command prompt does not wait for graphical
programs to exit.

If the program is a batch file control is transferred and the rest of the calling batch file is not executed.

### Use Start command

```
start "" c:\windows\notepad.exe
```

Start starts a program and does not wait. Console programs start in a new window. Using the /b switch forces console programs into the same window, which negates the main purpose of Start.

Start uses the Windows graphical shell - same as typing in WinKey + R (Run dialog). Try

```
start shell:cache
```

Also note the first set of quotes, if any, MUST be the window title.

### Use Call command

Call is used to start batch files and wait for them to exit and continue the current batch file.

---

With Reference to `Start` and just typing a program name.

Help Windows Find Programs and Documents

Programs and documents can be added to the registry so typing their name without their path in the Start - Run dialog box or shortcut enables Windows to find them.

```
REGEDIT4
;The bolded name below is the name of the document or program, <filename>.<file extension> 

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\IE.txt]

;The @ means the path to the file is assigned to the default value for the key.
;The whole path in enclosed in a quotation mark ".

@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\IE.txt\""

;Optional Parameters. The semicolon means don't process the line. Remove it if you want to put it in the registry

;Informs the shell that the program accepts URLs.

;"useURL"="1"

;Sets the path that a program will use as its' default directory. This is commented out.

;"Path"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office\\"
```

### For a technical discussion.

CMD preprocesses commands and finds the file then calls `CreateProcess`. Start - Run dialog or the `Start` command uses `ShellExecuteEx` which eventually calls `CreateProcess`.

This is `CreateProcess` rules - note CMD provides full paths to `CreateProcess`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425

> 1.The directory from which the application loaded.
>
> 2.The current directory for the parent process.
>
> 3.The 32-bit Windows system directory. Use the GetSystemDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
>
> 4. The 16-bit Windows system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched. The name of this directory is System.
>
> 5.The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
>
> 6.The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable. Note that this function does not search the per-application path specified by the App Paths registry key. To include this per-application path in the search sequence, use the ShellExecute function.

`ShellExecuteEx` is here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759784(v=vs.85).aspx

CMD preprocessing is available on my Skydrive - originally from MS web site but no more. See Windows NT Command Shell Ch 2 https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvqkaKIXzvDieQFjUcKneSZhDjw

Answer (score 1):

you need to call `start application` when you want the application to launch and return immediately to the command shell for further commands.

(on Linux, closest equivalent of `start` is the `&` suffix)

Some commands have the ability to do that without `start` prefix. That's what you're experiencing.

On the other hand, if you want an application returning immediately to "block" the shell, prefix by `cmd /c`

Try `cmd /c taskmgr` for instance, you'll see it blocks the command window until you quit it.

About the question about `taskmgr`, the 3 possibilities amount to the same result:

- `taskmgr` is in system path: with or without full path the system finds it
- `taskmgr` returns to the command window immediately. In that case, `start` is redundant.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like `start` opens a separate command prompt window to run an application. See here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297(v=ws.11).aspx. Does that mean every time I click on a shortcut to a program in the Windows GUI start menu there is a command prompt running in the background for that program?

Comment: Follow up question: does that mean the Windows `start` prefix is the same as the Linux `&` suffix? Ex: in Linux: `leafpad &` is like in Windows: `start leafpad` (if leafpad were a Windows program)?

Comment: some applications are "windows only" applications, means that they won't open a console. Only "console" apps open a console. For instance, build some code with `gcc` & the `-mwindows` switch you won't get the console.