# Run second bat file if first has exit code 0

Tags: batch-file, return-value

I have a .bat file that runs daily, if the return value == 0 i need .bat2 to execute, else run .bat3
How would this be accomplished?

Comment: `Call Batch1 && Call Batch2 || Call Batch3`. See answer here for meaning of punctuation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820569/trouble-with-renaming-folders-and-sub-folders-using-batch. See `call /?` and previous link for why `call` is necessary (at least for `batch1`).

Comment: But this does not consider the return value argument?

Comment: Oh yes it does.

Comment: Are "" required for the "location/Batch1/2/3"?

Comment: `Call "c:\program files\Batch1" && Call c:\windows\Batch2 || Call "c:\windows\Batch3"`. Quotes must be used if path contains a space, otherwise optional.