# Start Command not allowing additional process to be created

Tags: batch-file, cmd

My Program opens a javascript server for listening. However when i run this in cmd

```
start "Runnning" /B CMD /C CALL "file\program.exe" 23 12
```

The Program is prevented from creating the process for the Javascript program. Any work arounds that work in (.bat) files are appreciated

Comment: Why using `start`, `cmd /C` and `call`? `start` should be enough, if even necessary...

Comment: See my answer here on HOW TO START programs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820569/trouble-with-renaming-folders-and-sub-folders-using-batch